# VBA treating dates differently in Excel 2016? Is there any documentation about this?

Tags: vba, excel, date, version

It seems that VBA has been changed in Excel 2016/2013, as far as it starts throwing errors on places, where it does not throw on Excel 2010.

The code below does the following:

- creates 17 dates in a the first row of the ActiveSheet;
- fills date array, with 4 values

  - one within the first row
  - one not in the first row
  - one in the year 1913
  - one before the year 1904
- it looks for each value and colors the cell in red if it is found;

**In Excel 2010, it runs smoothly, finding one value and not finding the other 3 as expected. Everything is ok.**

In Excel 2016/2013, it gets unhappy with the value before 1904 and throws an error

> Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

on the `Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(someDates(cnt))`.

So, it seems that in Excel 2016/2013 under the [Date1904](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel) rule, there is some kind of a check that is made that `04.01.1900` is before the year `1904` and thus it cannot be parsed to a date in the Excel date system? While in Excel 2010 this is not the case.

So the question - **Is this feature/behaviour documented?**

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = True
    Cells.Clear                                          'clearing up all.
    Dim cnt     As Long

    For cnt = 3 To 20
        Cells(1, cnt) = DateAdd("M", cnt, DateSerial(2016, 1, 1))
        Cells(1, cnt).NumberFormat = "MMM-YY"
    Next cnt

    Dim someDates(3)    As Date
    someDates(0) = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)               'exists
    someDates(1) = DateSerial(2012, 1, 1)               'does not exist in the range
    someDates(2) = 5000                                 '08.09.1913 (in VBA)
    someDates(3) = 5                                    '04.01.1900 (in VBA)

    Dim foundRange      As Range
    For cnt = LBound(someDates) To UBound(someDates)
        Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(someDates(cnt))   'Error 5 in Excel 2016
        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
            foundRange.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next cnt

    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False                        'all dates with 4 years back

End Sub
```

Why is November 2016 selected when searching for January 2016:

- [Range.Find not making a difference between January and November (February and December) in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de)

Comment: Same observation here (Works fine in Excel 2007, raise an error in Excel 2016). Btw, why does Find returns a cell for `someDates(0)`?

Comment: To answer your question: no I don't think this is documented explicitly. BTW this problem also occurs in Excel 2013. Personally I always avoid using the date minefield of VBA date datatype, the associated implicit conversion of Range.Value coupled with the rather problematic .Find and stick to treating dates as doubles and using .value2

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - now you really have a point to call it minefield.

Comment: @Vityata I'm probably missing something, could you develop? On my computer the code colors the J1 cell, with the November 2016 date. Even with a 4 year offset this cell shouldn't be "found". Is Find using string to compare the dates and messing up 11/1/2016 and 1/1/2016? I would have expected that it rather compare the numeric values.

Comment: @VincentG - you are absolutely right, it is mistaking November and January.

Comment: FWIW, the same problem shows up with Excel 2010 (november in red)

Comment: The Run time error 5 "Invalid procedure argument" is also clear since having `ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = True` the 5 = 1900-01-04 **is not a date**. First date is 0 = 1904-01-01.

Comment: @Vityata I would like to indicate that my Excel 2013 throws error as well. Do you know maybe what VBA version is in your Excel 2010? (VBA Editor->Help->Version)

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle - Actually 2013 and 2016 go together, my mistake in the previous comment. (mentioned by Charles Williams in the 2. comment) My VBA is `7`. I will rewrite the comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AxelRichter - What is not clear is that this is handled differently in Excel 2016/2013 and Excel 2010. E.g. in Excel 2016/2013 it throws an error and in Excel 2010 it does not throw an error.

Comment: @ashleedawg - I really do not get why do you think that I am not patient? Is it concerning the comment starting with "What is not clear..."? It answers a comment with the same word, thus I find it ok. Concerning the dates and their change - they do not change between the version, VBA simply responds differently to values, that are not a date in Excel 2010 and Excel 2016 - e.g. the exact same code from the question runs without an error in Excel 2010 and throws one in Excel 2016. Having said all of the above - Don't be afraid of asking anyone for anything in a forum :)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misinterpreted.  My bad - text can be terrible for that.  (My brother and I once didn't speak for 6 months because of a missing hyphen.  "I re-sent that email" became "I resent that email."...

Comment: Anyhow this seems like a silly thing to have to check but hit your [WINDOWS] key and start typing `REGIONAL` to find *"Change the Time, Date or Number Formats"*.  Check what it has for `Short Date` and `Long Date`... ie., the exact setting includes separators.  If that doesn't match your region's default ([listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#Listing)) it can cause issues like your having.

Comment: @ashleedawg - I would have access to Excel 2016 on Tuesday, thus I would be able to check there. Currently I am with 2010. Still, do you think that if I make the same `Short` and `Long` dates there then in 2013/2016 I should not be getting the error? Just curious - are you with 2013/2016? If yes, can you replicate the error?

Comment: re: dates, check out this answer (of mine) to a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48974394/8112776  beyond that I'm not sure at the moment.  Date problems can be unpredictable

Comment: @ashleedawg -it is an interesting topic, but in the case of the question it is entering the dates with `DateSerial()`, thus it cannot be the entry form.

Comment: Not sure if I have an explanation, however, you can correct the error by converting the date to a Double. E.g. `Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(CDbl(someDates(cnt)))`. This is working for me on Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1):

> It this feature / behaviour documented?

Well, let's say `yes`. Although does not specify that it will fail... it does say that the 1904 Date System `does not support` dates before `1904` [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel).

> In the 1904 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1, 1904

Nothing new for you above, I suppose.

> So, it seems that in Excel 2016/2013 under the Date1904 rule, there is some kind of a check that is made that 04.01.1900 is before the year 1904 and thus it cannot be parsed to a date in the Excel date system? While in Excel 2010 this is not the case

Perhaps it never should have worked? if you try the following code, it will fail to write on the `Worksheet` environment (Office 2016):

```
 Cells(1, 1) = CDate("01-01-1902")                    ' will fail to write the date only in Date1904
 Cells(1, 2) = CDate(-200)                            ' will fail to write the date (runtime error 1004)
```

So, it makes sense that you **fail to find something that should not be able to write** in the `Worksheet`.

The following code gives you the first serial date that fails in 1904 Date System -> `1461` (VBA / 1900 Date System: `31.12.1903`):

```
Public Sub TestMe2()
Dim strMsg As String
 On Error Resume Next
 ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = True
 For cnt = 5000 To 5 Step -1
    Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(CDate(cnt))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Error 5: cnt = 1461 (31.12.1903 in VBA)
        strMsg = "Range.Find failed for CDate(" & cnt & ")" & Chr(13) & _
            Err.Description
        MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation, "Gap found"
        GoTo Test2_End
    End If
    If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then foundRange.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 Next cnt
Test2_End:
 ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
End Sub
```

It means that when calling `Range.Find`, it does interpret `1461` as `31-12-1903`, so as per 1900 System. As the `Worksheet` is switched to the 1904 System, that date is not supported. So, **yes, there is some kind of conversion behind** to refer to `31-12-1903`; **otherwise**, for 1904 System, it would have tried to find `1/01/1908` (`1461` for 1904 System => which is `2923` for the 1900 System = `1461` + `1462`), and **the error would have not showed up** (1904 serial > 0).

I guess that what is on the `VBA` as `Date` preserves its identity, regardless of the *Date System* used in that specific `Worksheet`. However, when you go to do operations on the `Worksheet`, limitations apply. Not sure if it's a release cut, but I am pretty sure they had waited the chance to get rid of further support in this sense.

I don't think you can work it around at all, unless you avoid to mix source data using different systems. Even though, the comparisons using `Long` or `Double` (serial date) do not seem to work if you do not apply the `offset` of days.

The code below is a modification of yours, to find out about all the options there:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
Dim cnt As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, rnCell As Range
Dim txt As String
Dim bln1904 As Boolean, offsetDays As Integer, blnOffset As Boolean

 On Error Resume Next

 ' Select testing mode
 bln1904 = (vbYes = MsgBox("Switch temporarily to Date1904?", vbYesNo, "Date Mode"))
 ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = bln1904

 If bln1904 Then
    blnOffset = (vbYes = MsgBox("Apply Offset Days for 1904 to date serials? (1642 days)", vbYesNo, "Date Conversion"))
 Else
    blnOffset = False
 End If

 ' Fill in Worksheet test data
 Cells.Clear                                          'clearing up all.

 Cells(1, 1) = CDate("01-01-1902")                    ' will fail to write the date only in Date1904
 Cells(1, 2) = CDate(-200)                            ' will fail to write the date
 Cells(1, 3) = CDate("31-03-2012")                    ' in Date1904 will write 30-03-2008
 Cells(1, 4) = CDate("31-10-2012")                    ' in Date1904 will write 30-10-2008
 For cnt = 5 To 20
    Set rnCell = Cells(1, cnt)
    rnCell = DateAdd("M", cnt - 2, DateSerial(2016, 1, 1))
 Next
 For cnt = 1 To 20
    Set rnCell = Cells(1, cnt)
    With rnCell
        .NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YY"
        .ColumnWidth = 10
    End With
 Next cnt

 ' Fill in data to find
 Dim someDates(9)    As Date
 someDates(0) = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1) - IIf(bln1904 , offsetDays, 0)
 someDates(1) = 42370 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)   '01.01.2016 (in VBA)
 someDates(2) = CDate("01-04-2016") - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)
 someDates(3) = 42461 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)   '01.04.2016 (in VBA)
 someDates(4) = 42675 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)   '01.11.2016 (in VBA)
 someDates(5) = 40999 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)   '31.03.2012 (in VBA): 42461 - 1462
 someDates(6) = 41213 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)   '31.10.2012 (in VBA): 42675 - 1462
 someDates(7) = 1462 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)    '01.01.1904 (in VBA)
 someDates(8) = 1461 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)    '31.12.1903 (in VBA)
 someDates(9) = 5 - IIf(bln1904, offsetDays, 0)       '04.01.1900 (in VBA)

 Dim foundRange      As Range
 Err.Clear
 For cnt = LBound(someDates) To UBound(someDates)
    Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(someDates(cnt))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Error 5: cnt = 8
        strMsg = "Range.Find failed for date " & Format(someDates(cnt), "DD-MM-YYYY") & _
            ". cnt = " & cnt & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation, "Error found"
        GoTo Test_End:
    End If
    If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
        With foundRange
            .Interior.Color = vbGreen
            If Not (.Comment Is Nothing) Then txt = .Comment.Text
            If Not (Trim(txt) = vbNullString) Then .Comment.Delete
            txt = IIf(Trim(txt) = vbNullString, "Found for date(s): ", txt & ", ") & _
                "D" & cnt & " " & Format(someDates(cnt), "DD-MM-YYYY")
            .AddComment (txt)
            txt = vbNullString
        End With
    End If
 Next cnt

Test_End:
 ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False                        'all dates with 4 years back
End Sub
```

If you try the different options, will find out that without the offset, things get messed. Aside note, I am not quite sure as per how it confuses `January` with `November` (clearly a bug?)

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at the last code and change `bln104` to `bln1904`? But in general, it really seems that there was a "silent update". I found about this "feature" because it popped-up unexpectedly after switch to Office 2016. Thus, my idea for asking for documentation was that probably in the place for the documentation I would be able to find other "silent" updates as well.  Concerning the `January` and `November`, take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de).

Comment: @Vityata: thanks for the rectification and the link above. Fortunately, I do not have to do such searches, so that native `Find` is not something I have to rely on. However, if I had to, _converting_ to string `ISO8601`, and searching for the converted string is the way I would try to achieve it. There may be ways to do it using the same ranges (with no need to copy your source ranges to a new spreadsheet).