# Range.Find not making a difference between January and November (February and December) in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

Let's say that I have the following trivial task:

- Write the first date of the months from January 2016 to June 2018 on a row
- Find 01-January-2016 and color it in red
- Use `Range.Find()`

Thus, I create a code, looping from 1 to 30 and writing the first date of each month. Then I use `Rows(1).Find(CDate("01.01.2016"))` or `Rows(1).Find(DateSerial(2016,1,1))` and I consider my task almost ready.

I run the code and I see this in both Excel 2010 and Excel 2016:

[image]

**Question:**
Is there any reason behind it? Or is the `Range.Find()` function documented to act like this?

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Cells.Clear

    Dim cnt             As Long
    For cnt = 1 To 30
        Cells(1, cnt) = DateAdd("M", cnt - 1, DateSerial(2016, 1, 1))
        Cells(1, cnt).NumberFormat = "MMM-YY"
    Next cnt

    Dim foundRange      As Range
    Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(CDate("01.01.2016"))
    'Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(DateSerial(2016, 1, 1))  'the same false result
    'Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find("01.01.2016")             'does not find anything
    If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
        foundRange.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

End Sub
```

In general, the `Range.Find()` has an optional `After` parameter, which is the first cell of the `Range`. In our case, the `After` parameter is omitted, thus it is considered to be `A1` and it is checked last. If you stop the code after the first loop and you manually delete `Nov 16` from Excel, then you continue the code, it will return the cell `Jan 16` in red.

As far as November is considered found, it gives it back and it does not go further. The question is more like - in what logic is **1-November-2016** the same as **1-January-2016**, even partially?

Comment: `Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(DateSerial(2016, 1, 1), [A1], , xlWhole) `

Comment: Here's a complete guess. In US date format `1/1/2016` can be found in `11/1/2016`.

Comment: @FlorentB. - `LookAt:=xlWhole` has nothing to do with the search start. Try to write `Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(DateSerial(2016, 1, 1), after:=Range("AD1"))` and it will give the expected result.

Comment: @CallumDA - it makes perfect sense, **but** then `1/1/2016` could be found in `21/1/2016` as well. If you only change the code in the first loop like this `Cells(1, cnt) = DateAdd("M", cnt - 1, DateSerial(2016, 1, 21))`, then it should find something. And it does not find anything.

Comment: @Vityata again a guess, remember that in vba the dates will be looked at in EN-US format.  I believe you will also return Nov 11th,2016 when looking at jan 11th 2016.  As in EN-US it is `11/11/2016` and `1/11/2016` respectively.

Comment: @Vityata actually it does, if I use a new workbook. https://imgur.com/a/6pnLm

Comment: @ScottCraner - it looks like there is something like this, but why is it not working for any other patterns than `1` and `11`? E.g., there should be a way to trick it to think that `2.12.2016` is in `12.12.2016` and up to now I could not.

Comment: @Vityata  I have no idea, because you are correct I cannot make those work either.

Comment: Wait, it does do it if you start at feb 12th 2016, so it seems that the default start is AFTER A1 and not A1 itself. https://imgur.com/a/Ahs7G

Comment: I think the moral is, always set whether you want whole or part and the start cell.  Or just use `Application.Match` with the appropriate error handling. :)

Comment: @Scott Craner - default After parameter is A1, thus the one after it is the first checked. Will check later with the 12.December, afk.

Comment: yes see my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever `.Find(LookAt:=xlPart)` is used upon a range of dates, it takes the dates not with their [.Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value2-property-excel), but it silently converts them to `String` following the American date format - `MM/DD/YY` and looks into this string. The display format of the date in Excel is completely irrelevant, as long as the cell is formatted as a date.

Thus, every day of January can be found in November and every day of February  can be found in December as a substring, making possible 58 (or 59 in a leap year) different mistakes within a calendar year:

[image: List of dates for comparison]

---

In order to avoid this mistake, the best solution is to look at `xlWhole` explicitly. If it is not referred, `Range.Find()` looks for partial string.

Another issue is where `Range.Find` starts. According to [The Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)  It starts ***AFTER*** the supplied or default cell and only looks at the start cell after it cycles back.

> The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface. Notice that After must be a single cell in the range. **Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell.** If you do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range.

So, by not defining `XlWhole` and a start cell, the first cell that is searched is `B1` not `A1`, and it finds the date partially before finding the correct date when it cycles around.

So setting the start cell at the end of the range will do it:

```
Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(DateSerial(2016, 1, 1), [XFD1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your ansewr and the comments. `After` is a known thing. I have written about it below the code in the question, trying to explain exactly what you answer. Also wrote an article about it: http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-find-function-in-excel-does-not-return-the-first-value. I am looking for an answer, saying `1/11/2016` is found when we look for `1/1/2016`, because `1/1/2016` is partially in `11/1/2016`, because excel considers it as a string when looking for it.

Comment: Isn't that what I said in the paragraph after the quote.  I can put more on that if you want. Personally I would use match.

Comment: In your answer, the imporant thing is "and it finds the date partially". It is this way of partialling, which is interesting, thus I was thinking of an answer with all possibilities (they are not that many in 1 year), e.g. - `1/11/2016` is in `11/11/2016`. `2/11/2016` is in `12/11/2016`.  `2/12/2016` is in `12/12/2016`. The rest (`After` and `xlWhole`) are not really relevant to the "partial finding". And using `.Find()` is really not a great idea.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific answer, why not write your own?

Comment: Well, you have mentioned "I can put more on that if you want.", and so I thought about it. :)

Comment: @Vityata feel free to edit mine to include what you are looking for, you can even make it a community wiki.  That would probably be best, It will allow others to contribute, also.

Comment: I have been looking for anything that states that Find uses `.Value` and not `.Value2`, which it obviously is doing, but I can't find anything specific on that.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it, later :) I think only you are allowed to make it a wiki.

Comment: Did it. @Vityata

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it is finding 1 November, but you can fix it by specifying a value for the optional LookAt argument of the Find() method:

```
Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(CDate("01.01.2016"), Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In general, it is giving the first value that it finds. Concerning that the optional `After` parameter is empty, the Range("A1") is checked last, because it is the default value of the `After`. As far as November is considered found, it gives it back and it does not go further. The question is more like - in what logic is November the same as January?

Comment: Microsoft logic :)

Comment: Actually there is some logic behind the November and January results. See the wiki answer, I have tried to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found CDate to misbehave from time to time. This code appears to convert your date to a string first, not the numeric representation of the date. That conversion happens after you find the string. Since you mentioned it skips the first cell then the first date containing that string is 11/1/16.

```
debug.print cdate("01/01/16")
1/1/16

Set foundRange = Rows(1).Find(CDate(#1/1/2016#))
Debug.Print foundRange.Value2
42675
```