# Run-time Error 91 - Object Variable or with Block variable not set - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have the following snippet VBA:

```
DatetoRun = InputBox("How far back do you want to run the MI for?", "Date backing", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy"))

'Date validation for DatetoRun
If IsDate(DatetoRun) Then       
    DatetoRun = Format(CDate(DatetoRun), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dateStart = DatetoRun        
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a DATE in the correct format dd/mm/yyyy"
End If

Set found = Range("A:A").Find(what:=DatetoRun, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

iclearrow = found.Row
```

When executing it I keep getting the

> Object Variable or With Block variable not set

which confuses me as I am setting it:

```
Set found = Range("A:A").Find(what:=DatetoRun, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

The error happens on the last row:

```
iclearrow = found.Row
```

Not sure how or why this is happening. also sometime it will randomly work once, but then error out after. Nothing is consistent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have error handling scenario if `Find` failed to find `DatetoRun` in column A.

```
Set found = Range("A:A").Find(what:=DatetoRun, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not found Is Nothing Then ' find was successfull
    iclearrow = found.row
Else ' Find failed >> raise an error
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & DatetoRun, vbCritical
End If
```

**Note**: when searching for dates, they are actually stored as numeric values, so try using:

```
Set found = Range("A:A").Find(what:=CDbl(DatetoRun), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

**Edit 1:** Try the following line of  `Find` :

```
Set found = Range("A:A").Find(what:=DatetoRun, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart)
```

Comment: Ah that would makes sense :)

Comment: When using the "CDbl", i am now getting a Type-Miss-match on the variable "DatetoRun". This current being declared as a String.

Comment: Without that it works, but the find always returns Nothing?

Comment: @xTNAx what values are you entering in the `InputBox` ? what values and format ?

Comment: Its a date with the format of dd/mm/yyyy. it is defaulted with today's date, but user can edit it for past dates.

Comment: DatetoRun is declared as a Date and found is declared as a range

Answer (score 0):

What is the `DatetoRun` type of variable? I guess it is `Variant`.

As far as `Find()` and `Date` is following its own logic, converting values to string and searching them - [Range.Find not making a difference between January and November (February and December) in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de), then it is a good idea to parse `DatetoRun` to `Date` after the conditions.

Like this:
`DatetoRun = CDate(DatetoRun)`
Then, it will always be "found" in `Range("A:A")`, if it is present there. The `If Not found Is Nothing Then` is a good idea to be present as well.