# VBA Date Comparison not working

Tags: excel, vba

I've got part of my code:

```
o = Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets(1).Range("b:b").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
For k = o To 2 Step -1
dte = CDate(Replace(Cells(k, 8), ".", "/"))
Cells(k, 8) = dte
    If Cells(k, 8) < udate And Cells(k, 8) > udate2 Then
    Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

In previous parts of the code, user specifies dates for which he wants to obtain report (udate and udate2)
E.g. I Specify that I want to see only rows with dates between 09/01/2017 and 09/30/2017 (mm/dd/yyyy) and the rest will be deleted.
However this comparison doesn't work. 
When I make a breakpoint in the IF line to check the variables I see:

```
Cells(k,8)= 11/9/2017 udate= 9/1/2017 udate2= 9/30/2017
```

So according to my code, this row should be deleted, but it's not.
I already tried some other options like:

```
Cells(k, 8) < DateValue(udate) And Cells(k, 8) > DateValue(udate2)
```

or

```
Cells(k, 8).value < DateValue(udate) And Cells(k, 8).value > DateValue(udate2)
```

or

```
CDate(Cells(k, 8)) < CDate(udate) And Cells(k, 8) > CDate(udate2)
```

and a few more, but nothing works.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your Cells(k,8) is also in mm/dd/yyyy, and not in dd/mm/yyyy, as if that would be the case deletion shouldn't take place.

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de

Comment: How is `udate` declared? Is it a `Date`, a `Variant` or a `String`?

Comment: @Vityata udate and udate2 are declared as date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic is incorrect:

```
If Cells(k, 8) < udate And Cells(k, 8) > udate2 Then

if #11/9/2017# < #9/1/2017#  And #11/9/2017# > #9/30/2017#
```

will evaluate to false.

Perhaps you want:

```
If Cells(k, 8) < udate Or Cells(k, 8) > udate2 Then
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I started from Or, however previously I made some other mistake and I thought it is a reason of "Or", so I changed it to And and didn't go back to Or