# How to jump to the cell with current date when open an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have question regarding How to jump to the cell with current date when open an Excel file.

below are the links to my file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_5H6x6pA53OcbOyvtpRfXm6oLVnT1vVa/view

I have tried using below VBA macro but it didn;t work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Select
    x = Day(Date)
    Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Columns(2).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
End Sub
```

Please advise.

Comment: ① Please not that these smart quotes `“ ”` are not allowed in VBA only the normal ones `" "` are valid quotes for strings. ② *"didn't work"* is no error description. Always tell which error you get and in which code line.

Comment: Which is your answer right there ;)

Comment: I have tried changing that but still when I'm opening the file the pointing is not on the current date.

Comment: You realise searching for `Day(Date)` is searching for the number 2, today - and not actually today's date (02/08/2018 or 08/02/2018 if US)

Comment: Using .Find and dates can be a bit of a challange. To make sure you are trapped, add `LookAt:=xlWhole` parameter, otherwise the results can be a bit unexpected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de

Answer (score 0):

If you are already able to find/select the cell you want to "jump to", then just use the [`Range.Show` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/range-show-method-excel) to scroll it into view.  E.g.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim CellToShow AS Range
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    x = Day(Date)
    Set CellToShow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If CellToShow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Cell for day " & x & " found.", vbCritical
    Else
        With CellToShow
            .Select
            .Show 'Scroll the window to show the cell
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chronocidal I'm still unable to jump to the select cell (current date). Currently the date are not in one column but in one row. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you wanted to look in Row 2 instead of Column B, then change `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Find` to `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(2).Find`  Based on the way you had written your question I assumed that you were finding & activating the cell but not scrolling to it - you need to explain the issue better (include a description of "what I expect" vs "what I get"?) like Pᴇʜ says in the Question comments.