# Excel VBA: How to solve Run-time error '91'?

Tags: vba, excel

I get the error:

`Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

when I try to execute this code:

```
MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("2:2").Find(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Value, , , xlWhole)
```

Why? What is wrong with this row?

**EDIT**

The code works if I am managing text or numbers. But I have that issue what I have **dates** on `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5")` and `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("2:2")`.

Comment: The value is not being found so it is returning nothing.

Comment: Avoid making member calls on an object reference that has any chance of being `Nothing` at run-time. `Range.Find` returns `Nothing` when it doesn't find what it's looking for, so the single easiest way to avoid this error with `Range.Find`, is to capture the result in a `Range` object variable, then verify whether it's `Nothing`, and *then* make member calls against it *if it isn't*.

Comment: to confirm, you want to search ROW #2 (not the 2nd column) correct?

Answer (score 5):

Assign the `result` to a Range and use the `.Find()` to set the range. 
If nothing is found, then the `Range()` would be `Nothing`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim result As Range

    With Worksheets(1)
        Set result = .Range("2:2").Find("Something", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End With

    If Not result Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print result.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "Something is not on the second row!"
    End If

End Sub
```

The `LookAt:=xlWhole` argument is a must, if one is working with dates:

- [Range.Find not making a difference between January and November (February and December) in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de)
- [Excel.Range.Find Documentation](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find)

Comment: That ninja-edit is what earned you my upvote. Thank you for adding an explanation. You know how much I like "code dump" answers ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - noone likes them. :)

Comment: @Vityata thanks but it does not solve the issue. Consider that I am managing dates. My code works when using texts or numbers but not with dates.

Comment: @Stefano - dates are a bit more difficult. See the edit. There you should always put `xlWhole` as the LookAt argument - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de