# unable to type into username box in website

Tags: excel, vba

There is a website, i have login. I am unable to type into the input box of the logon form.

I tried to get the associated object with the tag name "input" but i am unable to retrieve it.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim HTML1, HTML2 As HTMLDocument

URL = "xxxx"
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate URL
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Set HTML = ie.document
Set HTML1 = HTML.getElementById("_id0")

Debug.Print HTML.getElementByTagName()   '-----------------------------------------Not able to get the tag name
Call HTML1.getElementById("logon:").setAttribute("value", "username")    '---------Neither able to update the username & password too
```

---

Here is the inspect element of the page

I should be able to populate user name & password
[image: picture of HTML Source]

Comment: try getElementByID using the full id "_id0:Logon:CMS:row"

Comment: thanks for looking into my request. The same issue again popping up. Run-time error 91  object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: Assign the result to a Range and use the .Find() to set the range. If nothing is found, then the Range() would be Nothing. see link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504282/excel-vba-how-to-solve-run-time-error-91

Answer (score 0):

**VBA Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set Internet Explorer Controls**

Try something like this to wait until the element is available before clicking it. I've used HTMLGeneric element because I don't know what type of elements you are dealing with.

```
Dim element As HTMLGenericElement

Do
    Set element = HTMLdoc.all("eomSearchMain:advOrderSearch")
    DoEvents
Loop While element Is Nothing
element.Click
'IE busy And readyState wait here
'Document.readyState wait here

Do
    Set element = HTMLdoc.getElementById("frmOrderListing:lOrderListing:0:optxtOrderNumberActionFocusLink")
    DoEvents
Loop While element Is Nothing
element.Click
'IE busy And readyState wait here
'Document.readyState wait here
```

credit: [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1051160-vba-run-time-error-91-object-variable-block-variable-not-set-internet-explorer-controls.html)