# VBA Range.Find() function not working with large floating numbers

Tags: excel, vba, range, max, long-integer

I am writing code to lookup the highest dollar amount in a column and bring back the value as well as the value of cells in adjacent columns with 9 char in the target cell

When I set the range variable it shows the value of "12000.88" which works fine, however as soon as that value extends to over 9 digits "123000.55" the "set fnd" doesn't find it and the range variable is Nothing. I have tested many other things and have found the only difference is the length of the value

```
Sub Populate()

    Dim Fnd As Range    
    Set Fnd = Range("L:L").Find(WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("L:L"), 1), , xlValues)

End Sub
```

I have no problem with smaller numbers but I don't understand why this wouldn't work with larger numbers.

Comment: It works with`xlformulas` - don't ask me why!

Comment: And if the whole column is empty, it throws 1004 error.

Comment: I have been banging my head on this for about 8 hours... xlformulas... it works... so frustrated but relieved. Thanks.

Comment: @JeffF - `Find` is really a bit buggy sometimes, giving unexpected outcome with doubles and dates. Usually if possible I write my own function (and loop slowly) or parse to string. [Find bugs example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the different decimal separators that Excel and VBA are using. Thus, in the floating point values, there is a "hidden feature". The `Find()` function actually looks for a `string` and the double is "stringified" obviously not the correct way - with a comma and not with a dot. Consider parsing to string and replacing the comma with a dot to make it work:

```
Sub Populate()

    Dim foo As Range        
    Dim biggus As Double

    biggus = WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("A:A"), 1)
    Set foo = Range("A:A").Find(ReplaceCommas(biggus), , xlValues)

    Debug.Print foo.Address

End Sub

Function ReplaceCommas(valueAsString As Variant) As String

    Dim valueToReplace  As String
    valueToReplace = valueAsString
    ReplaceCommas = Replace(valueAsString, ",", ".")

End Function
```

The fact that the "feature", does not appear, when `xlFormulas`, is in the `SearchIn` parameter, is due to the fact, that `xlFormulas` converts the content of the cell to string, in order to search in it. E.g., if there is `=SUM(A1+A2)` and we are looking for `1+A`, the only way to find it is to parse the content of the cell to String.

Comment: @SJR - I just thought it is buggy. Anyway, the problem is in the `,` and the `.`. VBA uses dot and Excel uses comma as a decimal separator. I have edited.

Comment: @JvdV - same with me actually. I have edited it to make it work.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the answer. While it obviously would work since you parse values as string, the `What` parameter of `Find` [can take any excel data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). And if we first try to inspect the variable `WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("A:A"), 1)` we can see that VBA stores it with a dot since its en_US based. You sure it's a bug and `Find` takes strings only? Why would under 9 chars work? Furthermore, why would `xlFormulas` work. I'm also trying to make sense of this atm. =)

Comment: @JvdV - `WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("A:A"), 1)` works correctly and passes it to the `biggus` variable of type `double` correctly. The problem appears when the `A:A` column is searched for that variable - it "reads" wrongly the dots and the commas, thus it cannot find it.

Comment: @JvdV - concerning the other questions - `Find()` does not takes strings only, but it parses to string the arguments and thus the problem appears. The under 9 chars functioning should be some kind of optimization, in order to make the function quick, I guess. And about `xlFormulas` automatically converts the input of the cell to string, thus it works. After all, `=SUM(A1+A2)` is a pure string (e.g., not a `Long`, nor `Date`, nor `Double`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Vityata. Still find the whole operation weird and buggy but it also strangely makes sense. Ohwell. + For the research on this. =)