# excel vba moving the offset to start of the range if exist (functional way of writing)

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

Goal is to identify the start of the region value and it will be used in offset.

1. Input will be dynamic
2. Row length is not fixed.
3. Only criteria is region begin and end, but it may exist or not (see the sample input below)

| Criteria | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Sample Input | 1 to 10 |
| Region begin | 4 |
| Region end | 7 |

I have written the following code in **procedural way**, is there a better **functional way** of writing the following code for better management and readability?

```vb
Sub findBorder()
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    
    ' (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
    Set myrange = Range("D1:D10")
    Dim mark_region_begin As Integer
    Dim mark_region_end As Integer
    
    Dim mark_region_after_begin As Integer
    Dim mark_region_before_end As Integer
    
    Range("F1").Value = ""
    Range("F2").Value = ""
    Range("F3").Value = ""
    
    ' Find in bewteen and including 4 & 7
    For Each rCell In myrange:
        If rCell.Value = 4 Then
            mark_region_begin = rCell.Row
        ElseIf rCell.Value > 4 And rCell.Value < 7 Then
            If mark_region_after_begin = 0 Then
                mark_region_after_begin = rCell.Row
            End If
            mark_region_end = rCell.Row
        ElseIf rCell.Value = 7 Then
            If mark_region_begin = 0 Then
                mark_region_begin = rCell.Row
            End If
            mark_region_end = rCell.Row
        End If
    Next rCell
    
    If mark_region_begin = 0 Then
        mark_region_begin = mark_region_after_begin
    End If
    
    Range("F1").Value = mark_region_begin
    Range("F2").Value = mark_region_after_begin
    Range("F3").Value = mark_region_end
    
End Sub
```

**Sample input:**
[image]

In the following sample input, The column **E** is sorted, and the data in the range between **-0.15 to +0.15** will be selected.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4190.65 | 4227.6 | 4332.717 | 19.79 | -7.05 |
| 721.05 | 734.65 | 741.9 | 12.25 | -6.80 |
| 4273.05 | 4303.5 | 4420.3 | 14.89 | -6.60 |
| 1132.25 | 1150.3 | 1180.75 | 2.56 | -6.54 |
| 1134.55 | 1140.6 | 1168.317 | 22.12 | -6.47 |
| 4015.5 | 4030.4 | 4135.3 | 13.94 | -6.34 |
| 597 | 608.6 | 617.8 | 4.19 | -5.82 |
| 1355 | 1360.95 | 1385.317 | 2.95 | -5.60 |
| 2104.1 | 2116.55 | 2158.483 | 6.93 | -5.49 |
| 808.9 | 816.45 | 830.8167 | 1.54 | -5.39 |
| 367.2 | 370 | 377.0667 | 7.87 | -5.29 |
| 347.75 | 349.65 | 357.2167 | 3.28 | -5.18 |
| 7045.1 | 7178.65 | 7178.633 | 11.76 | -5.03 |
| 515.9 | 521.95 | 529.3 | 4.05 | -4.91 |
| 2002.4 | 2026.3 | 2071.267 | 4.24 | -4.88 |
| 100.5 | 101.2 | 102.7 | 2.36 | -4.78 |
| 116.95 | 117.7 | 119.4833 | 17.83 | -4.75 |
| 460.85 | 463.1 | 468.8 | 2.21 | -4.69 |
| 2326.1 | 2343.6 | 2379.25 | 8.58 | -4.49 |
| 193.8 | 196.25 | 198.85 | 0.71 | -4.49 |
| 2277.7 | 2290.4 | 2327.683 | 6.18 | -4.39 |
| 711.25 | 714.5 | 726.75 | 3.32 | -4.34 |
| 14285.7 | 14354.5 | 14580.02 | 5.18 | -4.33 |
| 6310.1 | 6365.15 | 6456.383 | 4.51 | -4.31 |
| 119.2 | 120.65 | 122.6167 | 12.48 | -4.31 |
| 80.8 | 81.3 | 82.96667 | 1.11 | -4.29 |
| 1537.25 | 1549.45 | 1585.133 | 6.86 | -4.23 |
| 778.05 | 785.75 | 797.9333 | 7.22 | -4.18 |
| 459.85 | 461.55 | 468.8 | -0.05 | -4.15 |
| 2406.15 | 2413.75 | 2457.283 | 2.79 | -4.15 |
| 243 | 244.7 | 249.05 | 0.55 | -4.14 |
| 742.6 | 751.3 | 759.9167 | 7.98 | -4.13 |
| 310.75 | 312.85 | 317.8167 | 0.81 | -4.13 |
| 108.05 | 108.7 | 110.8167 | 5.24 | -4.10 |
| 912.7 | 922 | 932.5667 | 3.01 | -4.06 |
| 626.1 | 629.55 | 637.3666 | 8.14 | -3.89 |
| 3767.4 | 3800.95 | 3871.116 | 11.39 | -3.88 |
| 4333.15 | 4348.5 | 4406.033 | 6.91 | -3.88 |
| 1444.55 | 1449.9 | 1469.15 | 4.14 | -3.83 |
| 2303.15 | 2324.6 | 2347.9 | 8.44 | -3.77 |
| 1036.05 | 1043.35 | 1058.967 | 1.72 | -3.77 |
| 685.9 | 688.6 | 696.3499 | 1.75 | -3.74 |
| 2242.95 | 2263.4 | 2292.116 | 1.84 | -3.73 |
| 1492.35 | 1500.3 | 1527.467 | 10.11 | -3.68 |
| 2436.5 | 2488.7 | 2506.85 | 6.64 | -3.64 |
| 1795.85 | 1804.5 | 1821.783 | 2.37 | -3.62 |
| 972.2 | 978.9 | 994.8667 | 2.7 | -3.61 |
| 2686 | 2696.85 | 2728.3 | 4.57 | -3.59 |
| 1620.15 | 1627.35 | 1649.75 | 2.06 | -3.55 |
| 145.5 | 146.45 | 150.0667 | 2.77 | -3.46 |
| 419.45 | 421.6 | 427.1 | 4.48 | -3.31 |
| 196 | 203.8 | 204.1333 | 3.73 | -3.29 |
| 266.5 | 268.25 | 271.6167 | 0.79 | -3.28 |
| 3978.4 | 4003.5 | 4041.25 | 3.48 | -3.27 |
| 338.5 | 339.55 | 343.5 | 1.63 | -3.26 |
| 1899.3 | 1909.65 | 1934.583 | 0.23 | -3.21 |
| 534.15 | 539.1 | 547.9167 | 1.77 | -3.20 |
| 221.25 | 223.1 | 227.0167 | 1.07 | -3.10 |
| 3371 | 3412.65 | 3443.45 | 2.25 | -3.09 |
| 3083.1 | 3102.8 | 3128.1 | 5.42 | -3.07 |
| 25129.5 | 25237.55 | 25722.35 | 3.99 | -3.06 |
| 2687 | 2703.05 | 2728.333 | 2.2 | -3.04 |
| 113 | 114.1 | 115.4833 | 0.59 | -3.03 |
| 3484.1 | 3498.85 | 3548.533 | 1.29 | -3.00 |
| 694.55 | 698.25 | 706.7333 | 3.17 | -2.99 |
| 1962.45 | 1978.05 | 2000.167 | 4.74 | -2.99 |
| 1339.55 | 1346.7 | 1359.667 | 3.89 | -2.98 |
| 229.2 | 231.8 | 234.0333 | 1.22 | -2.95 |
| 624.2 | 626.9 | 634.05 | 3.33 | -2.93 |
| 7372.05 | 7416.9 | 7516.267 | 0.64 | -2.92 |
| 367.7 | 369.35 | 373.6167 | 1.98 | -2.88 |
| 109.45 | 109.95 | 111.1833 | 1.79 | -2.87 |
| 1252.2 | 1258.3 | 1267.833 | 8.8 | -2.81 |
| 392.65 | 395.65 | 399.9333 | 4.08 | -2.79 |
| 323.75 | 326.95 | 330.4167 | 1.12 | -2.77 |
| 8446.35 | 8582.25 | 8631.017 | 1.04 | -2.76 |
| 706.25 | 709.95 | 718.1667 | 1.1 | -2.76 |
| 1320.6 | 1331.85 | 1349.333 | 13.81 | -2.76 |
| 476.6 | 479.3 | 484.4667 | 4.82 | -2.75 |
| 761.3 | 767.35 | 779.0334 | 3.47 | -2.75 |
| 2152.05 | 2173.95 | 2193.667 | 0.9 | -2.75 |
| 716.3 | 718.95 | 727.75 | 0.29 | -2.72 |
| 110.8 | 111.4 | 112.9333 | 2.11 | -2.71 |
| 2405.95 | 2417.15 | 2451.2 | 2.72 | -2.67 |
| 69892.8 | 70396.05 | 71025.88 | 3.6 | -2.63 |
| 16210 | 16280.9 | 16376.4 | 13.1 | -2.59 |
| 6507.75 | 6526.7 | 6585.333 | 3.54 | -2.56 |
| 2197 | 2210.75 | 2229.35 | 5.88 | -2.55 |
| 718.25 | 722.6 | 727.2333 | 1.12 | -2.54 |
| 258.15 | 259.85 | 263.1833 | 2.28 | -2.54 |
| 710.3 | 713.65 | 719.9333 | 3.07 | -2.52 |
| 16600 | 16722.15 | 16797.17 | -0.74 | -2.51 |
| 366.1 | 369.55 | 373.1 | 5.47 | -2.47 |
| 825 | 827.85 | 837.8167 | -0.17 | -2.47 |
| 113.95 | 114.3 | 115.45 | 3.82 | -2.43 |
| 517.75 | 521.65 | 526.95 | -0.04 | -2.42 |
| 93.95 | 94.95 | 95.9 | 3.31 | -2.42 |
| 35145.95 | 35308.15 | 35598.03 | 14.74 | -2.38 |
| 123.2 | 123.7 | 125.0167 | 2.39 | -2.37 |
| 894 | 899.85 | 906.1833 | 5.82 | -2.36 |
| 3194.8 | 3203 | 3231.267 | 4.6 | -2.35 |
| 156.4 | 157.05 | 158.6333 | -0.87 | -2.33 |
| 14110 | 14168.85 | 14268.67 | 6.25 | -2.33 |
| 1631.9 | 1640.3 | 1653.017 | 3.86 | -2.32 |
| 304 | 305.85 | 308.5333 | -1.25 | -2.32 |
| 896.2 | 901.6 | 907.6667 | 7.99 | -2.31 |
| 2742 | 2791.2 | 2808.5 | 3.55 | -2.30 |
| 433.75 | 438.5 | 443.45 | -0.87 | -2.24 |
| 572.85 | 578.9 | 583.2167 | 0.93 | -2.21 |
| 2466.35 | 2493.85 | 2511.3 | 6.7 | -2.20 |
| 2199.85 | 2204.25 | 2223.95 | 2.93 | -2.20 |
| 2008.9 | 2022.05 | 2035.367 | 2.78 | -2.19 |
| 442.2 | 448 | 451.7333 | -1.46 | -2.19 |
| 199.4 | 200.05 | 202.0333 | 4.69 | -2.18 |
| 129.75 | 130.6 | 131.8667 | 4.3 | -2.17 |
| 2666.05 | 2691.8 | 2711.833 | 3.22 | -2.16 |
| 950.45 | 958.45 | 964.05 | 3.02 | -2.15 |
| 16643.2 | 16702.5 | 16827.82 | 25.56 | -2.15 |
| 254.85 | 257.85 | 260.7 | -1.22 | -2.15 |
| 724 | 727.05 | 733.55 | 2.57 | -2.14 |
| 982 | 986 | 997.45 | 9.45 | -2.12 |
| 750.2 | 757.7 | 764.95 | 0.06 | -2.11 |
| 421.25 | 424.05 | 428.95 | 1.21 | -2.11 |
| 3815.25 | 3842.65 | 3881.384 | -1.83 | -2.07 |
| 603.1 | 609.25 | 611.9667 | 0.52 | -2.05 |
| 255.2 | 258.35 | 260.4667 | 2.8 | -2.03 |
| 540.6 | 543.45 | 548.0167 | 2.05 | -2.03 |
| 802.5 | 805.9 | 812.9333 | 4.24 | -2.02 |
| 2420 | 2435.65 | 2454.883 | 4.32 | -1.99 |
| 18000 | 18106.2 | 18219.4 | 4.03 | -1.98 |
| 276.45 | 279 | 281.5334 | 2.91 | -1.94 |
| 2007.65 | 2018.05 | 2031.683 | 3.32 | -1.93 |
| 507.25 | 512.55 | 515.4167 | 2.74 | -1.90 |
| 723 | 727.75 | 734.4 | 1.88 | -1.88 |
| 1040.45 | 1049.45 | 1056.6 | 3.19 | -1.85 |
| 566.2 | 569.4 | 572.4666 | 2.48 | -1.84 |
| 2275 | 2300.25 | 2313.417 | -0.77 | -1.82 |
| 54.8 | 55.25 | 55.93333 | 0.2 | -1.77 |
| 366 | 367.75 | 370.5333 | 1.82 | -1.74 |
| 39067.45 | 39122.3 | 39462.92 | 5.62 | -1.73 |
| 1776.35 | 1781.6 | 1793.317 | 3.87 | -1.69 |
| 1205.25 | 1217.45 | 1224.033 | 3.62 | -1.67 |
| 1248.4 | 1254.4 | 1265.267 | 0.87 | -1.67 |
| 1595.25 | 1598.65 | 1611.25 | 4.68 | -1.60 |
| 131.6 | 132.2 | 133.5333 | -0.9 | -1.56 |
| 1559.9 | 1566.7 | 1576.75 | -2.17 | -1.56 |
| 1258.8 | 1265.05 | 1282.95 | 7.18 | -1.47 |
| 1010.6 | 1015 | 1022.533 | 0.25 | -1.38 |
| 3471.25 | 3483.45 | 3507.783 | 3.35 | -1.29 |
| 198.6 | 200.2 | 201.8667 | 5.44 | -1.28 |
| 1620.7 | 1629.5 | 1640.817 | 2.78 | -1.26 |
| 4034.2 | 4053.5 | 4088.75 | -1.13 | -1.25 |
| 178.05 | 179.95 | 182.95 | 12.54 | -1.21 |
| 258.2 | 259.3 | 260.9 | 8.69 | -1.18 |
| 834.4 | 838.8 | 842.7334 | -2.55 | -1.10 |
| 360.55 | 363.8 | 365.4666 | 0.93 | -1.09 |
| 529.5 | 530.9 | 535.1334 | 4.22 | -1.05 |
| 4102.2 | 4125.15 | 4159.05 | 0.64 | -1.02 |
| 243.75 | 245.9 | 248.15 | 0.9 | -0.90 |
| 93.9 | 94.55 | 95.56667 | 0.47 | -0.84 |
| 668.5 | 674.3 | 680.2 | -0.89 | -0.81 |
| 2086.2 | 2099.35 | 2110.583 | 8.33 | -0.81 |
| 338.85 | 343.95 | 344.25 | 2.12 | -0.75 |
| 818 | 825.95 | 831.2834 | 3.78 | -0.73 |
| 490.75 | 493.8 | 496.7 | 0.7 | -0.71 |
| 898.2 | 911 | 912.0334 | 1.71 | -0.68 |
| 823.1 | 829.9 | 834.7834 | 4.77 | -0.62 |
| 45142.85 | 45377.95 | 45544.61 | 5.69 | -0.61 |
| 1270.9 | 1279.05 | 1281.983 | 0.57 | -0.53 |
| 516.25 | 519.8 | 524.5667 | 1.34 | -0.52 |
| 3914.1 | 3943.4 | 3963.833 | 3.67 | -0.52 |
| 125.6 | 126.4 | 127.0667 | 0.27 | -0.51 |
| 764.15 | 768.5 | 771.2166 | 1.87 | -0.47 |
| 3451.15 | 3480.1 | 3497.316 | 0.55 | -0.30 |
| 1067.5 | 1080.7 | 1081.767 | 1.77 | -0.28 |
| 638.2 | 642.85 | 644.65 | 1.74 | -0.26 |
| 1536.45 | 1542.05 | 1550.75 | 2.02 | -0.13 |
| 401 | 406.15 | 407.6167 | 2.21 | -0.09 |
| 2267.2 | 2296.15 | 2313.85 | 5.95 | -0.03 |
| 270.7 | 272.3 | 273.4833 | 0.48 | -0.02 |
| 156.5 | 158.1 | 158.4167 | 0.87 | 0.00 |
| 186.9 | 187.9 | 188.65 | 0.89 | 0.03 |
| 1572.2 | 1585.25 | 1590.95 | 0.02 | 0.15 |
| 1206.15 | 1214.65 | 1219.1 | 1.75 | 0.23 |
| 1770.5 | 1783.5 | 1794.05 | 6.99 | 0.24 |
| 116.35 | 117.35 | 118.95 | 4.16 | 0.25 |
| 4690 | 4744.95 | 4754.633 | 0.35 | 0.29 |
| 1031 | 1039.4 | 1042.133 | 3.65 | 0.41 |
| 151.3 | 152.5 | 153.5667 | 1.62 | 0.63 |
| 157.6 | 158.8 | 159.5 | 2.88 | 0.92 |
| 486.2 | 497.4 | 495.3333 | -9.39 | 1.67 |
| 233.65 | 237.9 | 237.0833 | 4.66 | 2.65 |
| 208.4 | 213.8 | 212.3833 | 1.64 | 2.66 |
| 158.45 | 162.75 | 161.5667 | -1.41 | 3.69 |
| 3344.9 | 3395.5 | 3447.267 | 11.16 | 3.71 |
| 168.4 | 176.5 | 174.7667 | 19.57 | 5.77 |

Comment: This seems interesting, but can you please explain it better. It is not clear at all to me what your objective is.

Comment: Perhaps show more of the sheet with the input and output and the column names and row numbers...

Comment: hmmm - column E doesn't look like sorted. Couldn't you use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answer to your question. But if I understand you correctly,

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range
Dim minVal As Integer
Dim maxVal As Integer
Dim oBegin As String
Dim oAfterBegin As String
Dim oEnd As String

With ActiveSheet
    Set rg = .Range("E1:E20")
    minVal = .Evaluate("min(if(" & rg.Address & ">=3.5," & rg.Address & "))")
    maxVal = .Evaluate("max(if(" & rg.Address & "<=11.5," & rg.Address & "))")

    oBegin = rg.Find(minVal).Address
    oAfterBegin = Range(oBegin).Offset(1, 0).Address
    oEnd = rg.Find(maxVal).Address
End With

End Sub
```

The code assumed that the data to be test is in cell E1 to E20 and already sorted.
Example data in column E from row 1 to 20 is a number from 1 to 20 on each row.
The goal is to find the cell address which contain :

1. the nearest bigger or equal number of 3.5 ---> this will be the row which contains number 4 in column E.
2. the nearest less or equal number of 11.5 ---> this will be the row which contains number 11 in column E.

To get point-1 result, the code using MIN function then keep it in minVal variable
To get point-2 result, the code using MAX function then keep it in maxVal variable

Then the code find the value of minVal/maxVal and get the address of the found cell.

So,
the oBegin variable value will be cell E4 ($E$4 which contains a number : 4)
the oEnd variable value will be cell E11 ($E$11 which contains a number : 11)
the oAfterBegin variable value will be $E$5

Comment: 1) Changing Integer to Double works.
```
Dim minVal As Integer
Dim maxVal As Integer
```

2) But 'range.find(minVal).Address' could not find it, when minVal is changed to double

Related reference:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310151/vba-range-find-function-not-working-with-large-floating-numbers)

Comment: (1) You are correct. I'm sorry, I should try the sample with decimal. (2). That's strange because in my side I can find it. Just now I copy your data sample table to Excel starting from E1 and the end of data is E196. Change the value to look, which is between -0.15 and 0.15. The minVal result -0.13 and the maxVal result 0.15. The oBegin show $E$177 (the cell contains -0.13) and the oEnd show $E$183 (the cell contains 0.15). Maybe try `oBegin = rg.Find(minVal, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Address` ?

Comment: Now "rg.Find(minVal).Address" is not working well because of decimal type. Here is a discussion related to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310151/vba-range-find-function-not-working-with-large-floating-numbers)

How to overcome this?