# Attempting to select a range if a specific date is present

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search a column that contains dates (exported in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss) and if a date value is today - 3 days (in short, I'll be running this task on a Monday, and would like to ID data from Friday) then select all cells on the same row, columns A:AK.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Fri()

Dim wrksht As Worksheet
Set wrksht = Sheets(";")

Dim Rng As Range

Dim Fri As Date
Fri = DateAdd("d", -3, Date)

Set Rng = Range("AL:AL").Find(What:=Fri, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Dim lr As Long
lr = wrksht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row          
        'wrksht.Range("AL2:AL" & lr).Formula = "=INT(H2)"
        'wrksht.Range("AL:AL").Copy
        'wrksht.Range("AL1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'wrksht.Range("AL2:AL" & lr).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"           

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then            
                Range("A" & Rng.Row & ":AK" & Rng.Row).Select                    
        Else            
                MsgBox "This date was not found in column H"                    
        End If

End Sub
```

I'm experiencing a few problems:

- it only works if I manually enter the formula in column AL and set the format to dd/mm/yyyy, entering the formula via VBA just returns the error message.
- it will only select the range of cells containing the first match - i.e. if my data set contains several rows with Friday's date in column H, only the row which contains the first instance will be selected.

Comment: Why not just use a filter?

Comment: The data is already ordered by date, I figured it just needs to be selected (because it needs to be copied to a few other documents) and using autofilter would make it slower and more complicated than it needs to be - guess I was wrong!

Comment: Dates can be tricky when using Find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula

Comment: Dates in November can be a bit tricky indeed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de

Comment: @SJR & @ Vityata You're both not wrong by the looks of those links, starting to think it would be simpler if I just selected the range manually...

Comment: Well they're not insurmountable issues, but you could consider using MATCH instead.