# Why is Match("text", A:A) function not working with text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-2010

Why is this formula not working:

[image]

I would expect to get 1 instead of 2.

Comment: You need to look for an exact match using the 3rd parameter of the `MATCH()` function. >> `=MATCH("s",A:A,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short story**

The correct way to use `Match()` and `Vlookup()` is always to write `False` at the latest optional parameter, in order to get what you need - exact value position or error, if it is not there. Thus:

```
=MATCH("s",A:A,False) 'or 0 instead of False
```

**Long story**

What is `False` default behaviour? This one as per [Match() documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a):

> MATCH finds the first value that is exactly equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument can be in any order.

Back to our question - **Why does it not work**? Because the default parameter `[match_type]` is set to `1`, which is `Less Than or Equal`:

[image]

- If you need to use `-1` or `1` as optional `match_type` arguments, then the values must be sorted to return some meaningful insight.

However what is "less than or equal" (the default `match_type` parameter) in this formula? If you ask Excel this is how it thinks:

```
="a">"s" 'False
="a"<"s" 'True
="a"="s" 'False
```

But, it still did *something wrong*. Why did it started to evaluate and compare with the second value `"a"` and returned its position, as if starting with the first cell would have fulfilled the "less or equal" condition? This really spices things up, as there are other "hidden" features of Excel coming here - e.g. [setting the first cell of a range to be the last to check, which is built-in in some functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935104/5448626).

So, it started to compare with `"a"`, found that it is less or equal and returned its position. Job done!

To completely lose everyone on this one, if you change the formula in the question to `=MATCH("s";A1:A2)`, it will return what you are expecting, thus the first cell being checked last functions depends on the type of the range.

Answer (score 1):

As @JvdV suggested you have to specify 3rd parameter `Match_Type` for older versions of excel.

```
=MATCH("s",A:A,0)
```

But for <kbd>Excel365</kbd> and `Google-Sheets` you can omit this parameter and excel will behave with default parameter.

Comment: The `MATCH` function in Excel O365 does **NOT** behave differently than the older versions.  You are probably thinking of a **DIFFERENT** function available in O365: `XMATCH`

Comment: I just tested match() without third parameter and works fine to my Excel365

Comment: Oh, it works, but given the OP's data, it returns `2` instead of `1`, just as it would in earlier versions.

Comment: Then must need specify match type.

Comment: Exactly. If you don't specify the match type `MATCH` uses the default, **both in the older versions and in 0365**, and returns the incorrect answer from the OP's point of view