# If date greater than or equal then function

Tags: vba, if-statement

```
Public DateRng As String

Private Sub DateLookup()

'Dim ColCnt As Integer

'Prompt Date to look for
  DateRng = InputBox("Insert date in format dd/mm/yy", "User date", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy"))
  If IsDate(DateRng) Then
    DateRng = Format(CDate(DateRng), "dd/mm/yy")
    ColumnDateCheck
'    MsgBox DateRng
  Else
    MsgBox "Wrong date format"
    Exit Sub
  End If



End Sub

Private Sub ColumnDateCheck()

    For C = 3 To 29
        If Cells(C, 2) >= DateRng Then
            'Function
            Cells(C, 5) = Cells(C, 3) + Cells(C, 4)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**Data in which code is performing on**

[image: Test Sheet]

Not having error executing code but function is not working as intended. It executes function in a mess without any pattern behind it. Can't understand output.

**Objective**

1. InputBox  in DateLookup sub prompts for date
2. If entry is valid, call out ColumnDateCheck Sub
3. Look for date entered in column B from Row 3 to 29. If date is greater or equal to, adds column C & D in  Column E.

Comment: what is your regional date format?  Like, if you run: `Msgbox Format(now(),"short date")` does it return the date in the same format you used in your code?

Comment: English (United States)

Comment: if you run if you run: `Msgbox Format(now(),"short date")` by itself, what do you get?

Comment: I'm getting 25/2/2018

Comment: hmm ok, I'll write an answer now

Comment: @ashleedawg appreciate it (:

Comment: Try  to compare the dates like this: if  Format(Cells(C, 2) ,"yyyy-mm-dd")>=  Format(DateRng,"yyyy-mm-dd") Then......etc.

Comment: @M.R. - instead I modified his code so it's in the proper format.  But funny that you choose that date format - that's what I manually set mine to on all devices because it's the most logical *and* it works for comparisons like your example since it's in the order of Largest→Smallest...  (just like "actual" numbers, lol)

Comment: @M.R. - plus you're , that's the other reason you use logical number formats.  :)

Comment: @M.R. - by the way, in comments you can display `code blocks` by surrounding the code with `\`` ... Other formatting tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use a USA date format (I use `y/m/d`) and neither do you apparently, since you're `d/m/y` and English/USA standard is `m/d/y`, so that was part of the problem (for both of us).

Regardless of how the cells are *formatted* in Excel, VBA still wants the date in a specific way.  There are a few ways to deal with that; I chose the easy one: make the user enter the date how Excel is expecting it.

So I added a function that will specify the format (which would be different for you and I and your computer).

The other part of the problem is that you need to better understand data types.  Basically, were trying to store a `Date` in a `String` variable, which doesn't always work as expected (like this time).

`InputBox` does return a string, so you do need to convert it, but converting it and still storing it in a String just keeps it a string.

Same with the statement: `DateRng = Format(CDate(DateRng), "dd/mm/yy")` since `Format` always returns a String (even if it "looks" like a date) and your `DateRng` variable is still a String.

Anyhow, this modified code should work:

```
Private Sub DateLookup()
    Dim str_DateRng As String
    Dim dateRng As Date
    str_DateRng = InputBox("Enter date in format " & DateFormat, "User date", _
        Format(Now(), DateFormat))
    If IsDate(str_DateRng) Then
        dateRng = CDate(str_DateRng)
        ColumnDateCheck (dateRng)
    Else
        MsgBox "Wrong date format"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ColumnDateCheck(dateToFind As Date)
    Dim c As Integer
    For c = 3 To 29
        If Cells(c, 2) >= dateToFind Then
            Cells(c, 5) = Cells(c, 3) + Cells(c, 4)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Function DateFormat() As String
    Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder)
        Case 0 : DateFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Case 1 : DateFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
        Case 2 : DateFormat = "yyyy/m/d"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing helping me solve the problem & explaining. Understood clearly (:

Comment: Good to hear.  I learned something too (been meaning to figure out a function to make date formatting a non-issue regardless of region).  [Here's a 6 minute basic YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/b_sp25kEai8) on VBA data types in case your interested.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare the dates like this:

```
   If Format(Cells(C, 2) ,"yyyy-mm-dd")>= Format(DateRng,"yyyy-mm-dd") Then......etc.
```

Comment: That won't help the fact that he's entering date in the `InputBox` in a non-standard format.