# Find Date() with Application.Match()

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find in a row the date of today (I'm using VBA Date to get today's date) But Application.Match doesn't find anything.

The code I'm using is this:

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Date, Range("5:5"), 0)
```

The dates in row 5 are generated by formulas, so I have to search the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how you are passing the date. In general, in `.Match()` the best way is to look for a specific numeric:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Range("E5") = Clng(Date)
    Debug.Print Application.Match(Clng(Date), Range("5:5"), 0)

    Range("E5") = ""
    Range("C5") = Clng(Date)
    Debug.Print Application.Match(Clng(Date), Range("5:5"), 0)

End Sub
```

Sometimes the date system in Excel are behaving a bit strangely:

- [VBA treating dates differently in Excel 2016? Is there any documentation about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925271/vba-treating-dates-differently-in-excel-2016-is-there-any-documentation-about-t)
- [Range.Find not making a difference between January and November (February and December) in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-de)
- [A bit more about Dates in Excel (joelonsoftware.com](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/))

Comment: shouldn't we use `CDbl(Date)` if the date is calculated by a formula `Match` uses the value of the cell not the text to match it I think.

Comment: @SolarMike - yes.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - `CDbl(Date)` would work as well. But it should be on both the formula and the assigning.

Comment: Strange, in my test `CStr(Date)` didn't work if the date in the cells is a date value (not text) formatted as date'. It doesn't match then even if they look the same text because `Match` only compares the value (which is numerical) but not the text.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - could be. Still, changed to `CLng` for `Date()`  it is quite ok.

Comment: So VBA treats Date like a string?
CLng(Date) worked for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: @A.Santos - actually it is a bit complicated. `Date()` is a number of dates, from `31.12.1899`. However, when searching, it searches for the string, unless told otherwise (at least I think so based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932196/range-find-not-making-a-difference-between-january-and-november-february-and-d)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date to Long:

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Date), Range("5:5"), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `MATCH()` with a VBA Date like this.  Instead use a `Long`:

```
Sub INeedADate()
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Date), Range("5:5"), 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

The above is an example of both the worksheet use of `MATCH()` and the VBA use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Match()` for comparing dates, it's only for strings.

You can use the functions `Year()`, `Month()` and `Day()`: if year, month and day are equal, then the date is equal.